# Reading PowerPoint Animation Effects with VBA

Tags: vba, animation, effects, powerpoint

I have been working with PowerPoint VBA, and have a grasp on most things.

What I am struggling with is reading the effect/animation settings for each object.

I seem to be able to get a lot of what I need through the `Powerpoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(slide_id).TimeLine.MainSequence(seq_num)`

What confuses me is how to convert the numeric value of `Powerpoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(slide_id).TimeLine.MainSequence(seq_num).EffectType` to an effect (so looking for a table of values to effects or perhaps a CONST table).

Also, how to read in all the different level of effects (like entrance, or emphasis, etc) is really confusing. not to mention I cannot wrap my head around the timeline (which seems like it is not really a timeline).

Can anyone point me to any good articles or documentation that discusses how to read the effects and animations properly and fully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some specific code that can demonstrate what is happening versus what you're after, that may be more helpful in determining what is failing for you. As far as I can discern, you're looking for a way to see the constants for the EffectType values, is that correct? Have you tried the `EffectInformation` object?

Here are some good primers on Animation in general:

**MSDN:**

- [Creating Animation Sequences in
  PowerPoint 2002 and PowerPoint 2003
  (Part 1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168134(v=office.11).aspx)
- [Creating Animation Sequences in
  PowerPoint 2002 and PowerPoint 2003
  (Part 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168135(office.11).aspx)

**MVP Article**

- [Timeline – The animation engine in
  PowerPoint 2002/2003 - Part I](http://skp.mvps.org/ppttimeline1.htm)
  (*there never was a Part II
  published*)

Note that PowerPoint 2002 throught to 2010 uses the new Animation engine so all/most 2002 samples will be applicable to later versions.

Comment: Thanks - i think that gives me a good starting point anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

For enumerations of the various effect values, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint(enumerations)